# Why we use 'no sooner' instead of 'not sooner'?

Tags: expressions

I think 'not sooner than' is a right form and 'no sooner than' seens pretty odd to me. Does anyone know where the phrase 'no sooner than' came from? Is it just a tradition?

Comment: It isn't a set phrase used only with *sooner*. You can be no uglier than your neighbor, no smarter than your spouse, etc.

Comment: This might be better-suited to EL&U.

Comment: "No sooner" is perfectly idiomatic. Why do you think otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

"Sooner" is a *comparative adverb*. You use it when you are not placing two things before or after one another but *comparing* their timing. It is **not** correct to say "not sooner than" because a comparison is not binary, unlike situations where something either *is* or *is not*. There may be a whole range of specific times down to the millisecond between two points. The phrase you may use instead if you want to say something must not occur until a specific time is "*not before*".

Examples:

> - You may open this gift **no sooner than** December 25th.
> - You may open this gift but **not before** December 25th.

It isn't just "sooner" that you use this way:

> - The oven should be *no hotter than* 180 degrees.
> - The oven temperature should *not* be *above* 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, it probably evolved over time, but if you don't use the "***than***" then

> **No sooner had he returned home that it started to rain**

is correct, but not

> **Not sooner had he returned home that it started to rain**

Answer (score 0):

The structure *no sooner...than* can be used If the second event occurs immediately after the first, and it introduces the event that occurred first. Beginning a sentence with the negative word *no*, the structure requires putting the auxiliary verb before the subject:

> No sooner had I arrived/did I arrive at the station than the train came.

This means that I arrived first and the train right after me.

[The source](https://www.englishgrammar.org/sooner-hardlywhen/)